# Haskell - Garbage collection fails to reclaim sufficient space

Tags: haskell, stack, stack-overflow

I'm doing a program to sum all odd numbers up to n:

```
oddSum' n result | n==0 = result
                 | otherwise = oddSum' (n-1) ((mod n 2)*(n)+result)

oddSum n = oddSum' n 0
```

I'm getting a two erros for for my inputs (I've put them below), I'm using tail recursion so why is the stack overflow happening? (note: I'm using Hugs on Ubuntu)

oddSum 20000
ERROR - Control stack overflow

oddSum 100000
ERROR - Garbage collection fails to reclaim sufficient space

Comment: Try to compile it with `ghc -O`, its strictness analyzer might detect that `oddSum'` is strict in the second argument and insert the required `seq`'s itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 oddSum 3
 oddSum 2 ((2 mod 2)*2 + 3)
 oddSum 1 ((1 mod 2)*1 + ((2 mod 2)*2 + 3))
```

You are building a huge thunk in the `result` variable.
Once you evaluate this, all the computations have to be done at once, and then the stack overflows, because, to perform addition, for example, you first have to evaluate the operands, and the operands of additions in the operands.

If, otoh, the thunk gets too big, you get a heap overflow.

Try using

```
result `seq` ((mod n 2) * n + result)
```

in the recursion.

Comment: thanks! I thought that putting parentheses in the mod n 2, making it (mod n 2) i would be forcing it to be evaluated.

Comment: no, it won't until the compiler can see that the value is actually needed in the function. For example, if you replace `otherwise` with `result >= 0` then this will force the code generated to evaluate `result` in each recursion. (But I do not advise doing so, it is a trick that impairs readability and also can't be applied everywhere.)

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, don't use Hugs, it's unsupported. With optimising GHC chances are something like this would be compiled to a tight efficient loop (still your code wouldn't be fine).

Nonstrict accumulators always pose the risk of building up huge thunks. One solution would be to make it strict:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns   #-}

oddSum' n !acc | n==0       = acc
               | otherwise  = oddSum' (n-1) $ (n`mod`2)*n + acc
```

Of course, that's hardly idiomatic; explicitly writing tail-recursive functions is cumbersome and somewhat frowned upon in Haskell. Most things of this kind can nicely be done with library functions, like

```
oddSum n = sum [1, 3 .. n]
```

...which unfortunately doesn't work reliably in constant space, either. It does work with the strict version of the fold (which `sum` is merely a specialisation of),

```
import Data.List
oddSum n = foldl' (+) 0 [1, 3 .. n]
```

Comment: I thought about doing it with lists, but opted for my own implementation as a way of learning and to not be too dependant of already implemented functions.
I'm at my university's computer lab, it only have Hugs and stundets can't install anything (i'm using ghc at home).

Comment: Hugs isn't supported, but Hugs *works*. It's not buggy, and it's fast to compile (it even notices when I edited my file, so I don't need to `:r`). It's limited to Haskell 98 and doesn't support GHC extensions, but it's great for learning on, partly because the error messages are much clearer, particularly it gives a type error where ghc tells you to go write an instance declaration.

Comment: Using Hugs with limited stack/heap has brought to light an important misunderstanding the OP had about evaluation in Haskell, where `ghc -O2` might have hidden it. We like to find out we did something wrong ASAP, don't we? `ghc -O2` during coding is slower than a `:r` (in ghci or hugs), less interactive, and premature optimisation.

Comment: BTW, I think using `$!` is nicer than bang patters. `oddSum' n acc | n==0 = acc` then `| otherwise = oddSum' (n-1) $! (mod n 2)*n + acc`